# Recomended Update Manager settings

Tags: update-manager, updates

What is the recommended update manager settings for a newbie in Ubuntu?. ¿Software sources configuration ?¿Recommended updates are useful and not problematic? Update weekly or daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you just leave the default settings for now, as they will provide only stable, important and secure software updates.